# map.insert - что я делаю не так?

Tags: c++, map

Что я делаю не так? Нужно просто написать функцию, которая значения из map переводит в set

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <set>
#include <string>
#include <map>

std::set<std::string> BuildMapValuesSet (const std::map<int, std::string>& mp){

  std::set<std::string> s;
  for(auto item : mp)
    {
        s.insert(item.first);

    }
  return s;
}


int main(){
  std::set<std::string> values = BuildMapValuesSet({
      {1, "odd"},
      {2, "even"},
      {3, "odd"},
      {4, "even"},
      {5, "odd"}
  });

  for (const std::string& value : values) {
    std::cout << value;
  }
}
```

Comment: Ну и почему `.first`?

Comment: @andy.37, a как обращаться к ключу или значению мэпа?

Comment: Ключ ( у вас `int`) - `.first`, значение - `.second`. `for (std::pair<int, std::string> item : mp) ...`

Comment: а ауто он не определяет тип? или я не совсем понимаю

Comment: @andy.37, спасибо! не думал что тут люди такие добрые, а то например на линукс орге сразу обсирают

Comment: Вы совершенно правильно используете `auto`. Я его раскрыл только для того, чтобы было понятнее, почему second, а не first.

Comment: @andy.37: Почему не как ответ?

Comment: @VladD, м что   ?

Comment: Почему в вопросе отсутствует описание сути проблемы? Вопросы, состоящие из "Что я делаю не так?" тут не приветствуются. В чем ваш вопрос? В чем проблема?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы понять в чем проблема вам следует переписать вашу функцию без использования `auto`:

```
for(std::pair<const int, std::string> item : mp){
    s.insert(item.second);
}
```

Теперь очевидно что `item.first` это ключ, а `item.second` это значение